# Jooq pojoImplements: view vs table

Tags: jooq

I have a database with both tables and views. I use JOOQ to generate java code to intercat with data.

I want that every pojo generated for any table implements my custom interface. I have accomplished that using pojoImplements.

This behaviour is required only for tables, I don't want that pojos generated for views implements that custom interface.

Is there any method, maybe in expressions?, to apply some rules to tables and other ones to views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to currently do this is by using the `<expression>` flag that matches object names, e.g.

```xml
<tables>
  <table>
    <expression>EXPRESSION_MATCHING_ONLY_TABLES</expression>
    <pojoImplements>...</pojoImplements>
  </table>
</tables>
```

You can either use a prefix in your regular expression, such as `T_.*?`, if you have strict naming conventions (e.g. `T_TABLE` and `V_VIEW`, etc.) or you'll have to match all table names explicitly.

If you're using the [programmatic code generator configuration](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-programmatic/), then you can generate that regular expression using a query. In PostgreSQL, that query could look like this:

```sql
SELECT string_agg(table_name, '|')
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
```